# Copy Specific file type from subfolders

Tags: c#, console, copy

I am new to C# and I am trying to build a console application to copy a specific file type .e.g *.txt that is nested within subfolders to be copied to another directory.

The directory looks something like this 
`C:\V1.1\Folder_*\Folder\Folder\Folder\Filetype.txt`

`*` meaning today's date

How would I get a list of files matching that pattern?

Comment: fixed some formatting.
explicitly stated the question

Comment: Use powershell maybe? Why do you need to have it coded in C#? `dir -recurse c:\v1.1\Folder_* -include *.txt` - that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
var path = String.Format(@"C:\V1.1\Folder_{0}\Folder\Folder\Folder",
            DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))

 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 var files=di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

You can check [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx) out for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I ended up doing this:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
```