# file.copy multiple files c#

Tags: c#, copy

I'm looking to see if there is a more efficient way of copying certain files from a folder to another folder.  There are a lot of files so i'm wondering if there's an easier way.  Thank you.

Example:

file1.jpg
file1.bmp
file1.gif

file2.jpg
file2.bmp
file2.bmp

```
if (chkbox1.Checked)
{
   File.Copy(sourcedir + "\\file1.jpg", targetdir + "\\file1.jpg", true); 
   File.Copy(sourcedir + "\\file1.bmp", targetdir + "\\file1.bmp", true);   
   File.Copy(sourcedir + "\\file1.gif", targetdir + "\\file1.gif", true);   
}

if (chkbox2.Checked)
{
   File.Copy(sourcedir + "\\file2.jpg", targetdir + "\\file2.jpg", true); 
   File.Copy(sourcedir + "\\file2.bmp", targetdir + "\\file2.bmp", true);   
   File.Copy(sourcedir + "\\file2.gif", targetdir + "\\file2.gif", true);   
}
```

Comment: What about a list of files and a  loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31046337/13532401

Comment: I just thought maybe there was a more efficient way because each batch is always composed of 3 files which are the same name except the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way of refactoring your code to reduce the repetition. It's not *more efficient*, but it will be easier to maintain:

```
    var file1Files = new List<string> { "file1.jpg", "file1.bmp", "file1.gif", };
    var file2Files = new List<string> { "file2.jpg", "file2.bmp", "file2.gif", };

    var files2copy = chkbox1.Checked ? file1Files : file2Files;

    foreach (var file in files2copy)
    {
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcedir, file), Path.Combine(targetdir, file), true);
    }
```

Unlike most of my answers, I haven't tested this code.  But I'm very confident that it's correct, or very close.

This is basically @John's comment, fleshed out with some code.

Comment: I might just rewrite my codes to this.  Thank you!

Comment: "var files2copy = chkbox1.Checked ? file1Files : file2Files;"
My only other question is this line.  I have a whole bunch of chkbox so it's not just either file1 OR file2.  I have 3,4,5,6,7,etc.  Any suggestion on how to handle it?

Comment: Does this mean i have to make a foreach loop for each checkbox?

Comment: I don't know. That's your code. You could, for example refactoring the loop into a function that takes an `IEnumerable<string> fileNames` as a parameter.